# Читать регистры DMA

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь с таким заданием:
Программа должна читать регистры начальных адресов и начальных счетчиков циклов каналов 4-7 контроллера DMA.
Я не смог найти примеры реализации или хороших статей на эту тему, скорее всего плохо искал, по этому не особо понимаю как я должен это реализовать, буду рад какой либо помощи или материалу.

Comment: Какая ОС, платформа?

Comment: Прежде всего -- *от какого именно производителя этот контроллер DMA*? Обычно эта документация на контроллер называется  Technical Reference Manual (TRM).   Там описание  регистров. Понятно, что регистры для каждого из каналов будут повторяться. А также, как минимум, вам надо знать базовый адрес контроллера в вашей системе.